# Vue.js use prop value as class name

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2

If I pass a class name to a component how do I use the value of that prop as the class name?

`<i v-if="icon" class="fa" :class="{ icon: icon }"></i>`

called with `<input-text icon="fa-search"></input-text>`

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can use array notation:

```
<i v-if="icon" :class="['fa', icon]"></i>
```

Where `icon` is a name of your property.